# SwiftUI: UserInterfaceSizeClass for Universal (macOS & iOS) Views

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, cross-platform, size-classes

Attempting to reference the `@Environment` objects `horizontalSizeClass` and `verticalSizeClass` on macOS (native, not Catalyst) results in the following errors:

> 'horizontalSizeClass' is unavailable in macOS

> 'verticalSizeClass' is unavailable in macOS

I appreciate that these properties aren't really applicable for macOS, but this presents a big barrier to creating SwiftUI Views which work universally (i.e. cross-platform across macOS, iOS, etc.).

One workaround is to wrap all the size-class-specific code inside conditional compilation, but the result is lots of duplication and redundancy (see below example).

Isn't there a more efficient way to handle this?

**Example Universal View:**

```
struct ExampleView: View {

    #if !os(macOS)
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    #endif

    private var item1: some View {
        Text("Example Item 1")
    }
    private var item2: some View {
        Text("Example Item 2")
    }
    private var item3: some View {
        Text("Example Item 3")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            #if !os(macOS)
            if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
                VStack {
                    item1
                    item2
                    item3
                }
            } else {
                HStack {
                    item1
                    item2
                    item3
                }
            }
            #else
            HStack {
                item1
                item2
                item3
            }
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's true that macOS doesn't support `horizontalSizeClass` and `verticalSizeClass` natively, but the good news is it's easy to add them.

You can define your own `@Environment` objects by making a `struct` that conforms to `EnvironmentKey`, then using it to extend `EnvironmentValues`.

All you need to implement size classes on macOS is the following. They just return `.regular` at all times, but it's enough to function exactly the same as on iOS.

```
#if os(macOS)
enum UserInterfaceSizeClass {
    case compact
    case regular
}

struct HorizontalSizeClassEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: UserInterfaceSizeClass = .regular
}
struct VerticalSizeClassEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: UserInterfaceSizeClass = .regular
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var horizontalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass {
        get { return self[HorizontalSizeClassEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[HorizontalSizeClassEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
    var verticalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass {
        get { return self[VerticalSizeClassEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[VerticalSizeClassEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
#endif
```

With this in place, you don't need anything special for macOS. For example:

```
struct ExampleView: View {

    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    
    private var item1: some View {
        Text("Example Item 1")
    }
    private var item2: some View {
        Text("Example Item 2")
    }
    private var item3: some View {
        Text("Example Item 3")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
                VStack {
                    item1
                    item2
                    item3
                }
            } else {
                HStack {
                    item1
                    item2
                    item3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can even put these extensions into a framework for broader use, so long as you define them as `public`.

Comment: In 2022 Swift, you'll need to add `.self` to the struct names: `return self[HorizontalSizeClassEnvironmentKey.self]`.

Comment: UserInterfaceSizeClass is available on macOS with Xcode 15

Comment: Hi. That should be written as an answer, not a comment. Thanks!